# Prepare email body for PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, bitrix

I stuck in a problem using 1C-Bitrix framework with PHPMailer. The problem connected with the email body.

1C-Bitrix framework prepares body depending on options enabled. For example, if I turn on the option "Create text vesion of html-email"  the body will look like this:

```
    ---------alt8045b59706
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

This is my email 

---------alt8045b59706
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

<h1> This is my email </h1>

---------alt8045b59706--
```

If I the email template will have an attached txt file, the body will look like this:

```
---------mix4215b5973f
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="-------alt3795b5973f"

---------alt3795b5973f
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

This is my email 

---------alt3795b5973f
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

<h1> This is my email </h1> 

---------alt3795b5973f--
---------mix4215b5973f
Content-Type: text/plain; name="=?UTF-8?B?dGVzdC50eHQ=?="
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <427605>

dGVzdCB0ZXh0Cg==

---------mix4215b5973f--
```

And, finally, the standard email body will look like this:

```
<h1> This is my email </h1>
```

I can't just feed such email body to PHPMailer. It doesn't work correctly. I tried msgHtml() - also doesn't work.

But standard php mail() func works well with such email body.
I found that in PHPMailer I need to set Body and AltBody separately. But then, what is the best way for me to parse such email body.

Maybe somebody knows a tool for it?
Or PHPMailer has a built in methods for it?
Maybe I need to just manually set correct "Content-Type" header (framework tells me correct Content-Type)

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to think about those things - PHPMailer does it for you. This is all you need to do to make that structure:

```
$mail->isHTML();
$mail->Body = '<h1> This is my email </h1>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is my email';
$mail->addAttachment('path/to/file.pdf');
```

Also, the MIME structure in the example you gave for the message body with an attachment is incorrect, so I wouldn't expect it to work in any context.

Comment: The thing is I've already has a prepared body(as I showed in examples) by the time I can start working with PhpMailer.  
For now I found a temporary solution by overriding PHPMailer::createBody() method. If I have "boundary" substring in a "Content-Type" header (set by my framework), I simply feed email body  (prepared by my framefork) to $this->Body. If no "boundary" substring, I call parent::createBody().
But using this method I miss some initialization ($this->boundary, $this->MIMEHeader) and completely miss encoding that parent method has.  
So is the best way for me is to parse body?

Comment: The best way is not to do it. Instead of going to the effort of building your own message, pass the same content to PHPMailer and get it to build the body for you - that’s what libraries are for. It doesn’t look like you’re doing anything unusual in the structure, so I’d recommend going with the flow. PHPMailer internals are not too pretty, and you’ll find lots of issues if you override important stuff.